# How To Tell If A PHP Variable is a Reference Variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting whether a PHP variable is a reference / referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817562/detecting-whether-a-php-variable-is-a-reference-referenced)

I am wondering if there is a function that will tell me if a variable is a reference variable. If there is not a specific function, is there a way to determine if it is a reference variable?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in function to check if a variable is a reference.

Comment: Interesting question, but I wonder what the use case is.

Comment: The use case was for debugging a variable that was changing unexpectedly.

Comment: If it's for debugging, just var_dump it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine this using [`debug_zval_dump`](http://php.net/debug_zval_dump). See my answer [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817562/detecting-whether-a-php-variable-is-a-reference-referenced/4817962#4817962).

Comment: If you've answered this on another question, why did you answer it here?

Answer (score 0):

From the [user examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php) it looks like there is no direct way, but you'll find a solution there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [this function from one of the commenters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php#103660) at PHP docs. But afaik there is not built-in function that would check if var is reference var.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
$c = 2;
$d = 3;
$e = array($a);
function is_reference($var){
    $val = $GLOBALS[$var];
    $tmpArray = array();
    /**
     * Add keys/values without reference
     */
    foreach($GLOBALS as $k => $v){
        if(!is_array($v)){
            $tmpArray[$k] = $v;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change value of rest variables
     */
    foreach($GLOBALS as $k => $v){
        if($k != 'GLOBALS'
            && $k != '_POST'
            && $k != '_GET'
            && $k != '_COOKIE'
            && $k != '_FILES'
            && $k != $var
            && !is_array($v)
        ){
            usleep(1);
            $GLOBALS[$k] = md5(microtime());
        }
    }

    $bool = $val != $GLOBALS[$var];

    /**
     * Restore defaults values
     */
    foreach($tmpArray as $k => $v){
        $GLOBALS[$k] = $v;
    }

    return $bool;
}
var_dump(is_reference('a'));
var_dump(is_reference('b'));
var_dump(is_reference('c'));
var_dump(is_reference('d'));
?>
```

This is an example from [the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php).