# Check arrays for recursion

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

What is the best way to check if an array is recursive in PHP ?

Given the following code:

```
<?php 
$myarray = array('test',123); 
$myarray[] = &$myarray; 
print_r($myarray); 
?>
```

From the [PHP Manual:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#73936)

> The print_r() will display *RECURSION* when it gets to the third
>   element of the array.
>
> There doesn't appear to be any other way to scan an array for
>   recursive references, so if you need to check for them, you'll have to
>   use print_r() with its second parameter to capture the output and look
>   for the word *RECURSION*.

Is there more elegant way of checking ?

PS. This is how I check and get the recursive array keys using regex and print_r()

```
$pattern = '/\n            \[(\w+)\] => Array\s+\*RECURSION\*/';
preg_match_all($pattern, print_r($value, TRUE), $matches);
$recursiveKeys =  array_unique($matches[1]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the _RECURSION_ term displayed just when it gets 3 elements  deep, not when it references itself? Also, I'm pretty sure that is a configurable depth in php.ini

Comment: I did this with objects using spl_object_hash() but for arrays I have no clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always fun to try solving "impossible" problems!

Here's a function that will detect recursive arrays if the recursion happens at the top level:

```
function is_recursive(array &$array) {
    static $uniqueObject;
    if (!$uniqueObject) {
        $uniqueObject = new stdClass;
    }

    foreach ($array as &$item) {
        if (!is_array($item)) {
            continue;
        }

        $item[] = $uniqueObject;
        $isRecursive = end($array) === $uniqueObject;
        array_pop($item);
        if ($isRecursive) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/OqTKSl)**.

Detecting recursion at *any* level would obviously be more tricky, but I think we can agree that it seems doable.

#### Update

And here is the recursive (pun not intended but enjoyable nonetheless) solution that detects recursion at any level:

```
function is_recursive(array &$array, array &$alreadySeen = array()) {
    static $uniqueObject;
    if (!$uniqueObject) {
        $uniqueObject = new stdClass;
    }

    $alreadySeen[] = &$array;

    foreach ($array as &$item) {
        if (!is_array($item)) {
            continue;
        }

        $item[] = $uniqueObject;
        $recursionDetected = false;
        foreach ($alreadySeen as $candidate) {
            if (end($candidate) === $uniqueObject) {
                $recursionDetected = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        array_pop($item);

        if ($recursionDetected || is_recursive($item, $alreadySeen)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/2IQwpQ)**.

Of course this can also be written to work with iteration instead of recursion by keeping a stack manually, which would help in cases where a very large recursion level is a problem.

Comment: Does not work for all arrays, see https://3v4l.org/V4K6r

Answer (score 3):

The following function is simpler[opinion] than the code in the accepted answer, and seems to work for any use case that I have been able to contrive.  It also seems to be surprisingly fast, typically taking microseconds, though I have not done extensive benchmarking.  If there is a problem with it, I would be grateful if somebody could point it out?

```
// returns TRUE iff the passed object or array contains
// a self-referencing object or array
function is_r($obj, &$visited=array())
  {
  $visited[] = $obj;
  foreach ($obj as $el)
    {
    if (is_object($el) || is_array($el))
      {
      if (in_array($el, $visited, TRUE))
        return TRUE;
      if (is_r($el, $visited))
        return TRUE;
      }
    }
  return FALSE;
  }
```

Comment: Nice one, simple and fast.

Answer (score 2):

I've dug into this in depth some time ago, and I was unable to find any useful mechanism for detecting recursion in PHP arrays.

The question boils down to whether it's possible to tell whether two PHP variables are references to the same thing.

If you're working with objects rather than arrays (or even objects within your arrays), then it is possible, as one can find out whether two objects are the same reference using `spl_object_hash()`. So if you have objects in your structure, then you can detect recursion by traversing up the tree and comparing the objects.

However for regular variables -- ie non-objects -- it isn't possible to detect this easily using standard PHP.

The work arounds are to use `print_r()` (as you already know) or `var_dump()`, but neither of these are particularly elegant solutions.

There is also a function provided by xDebug which can help, `xdebug_debug_zval()`, but that's obviously only available if you've got xDebug installed, which isn't recommended on a production system.

Further advice and suggestions [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817562/detecting-whether-a-php-variable-is-a-reference-referenced).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't check that. Read the [Reference<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php) for more information on reference.

Here is the function to check for RECURSION (from PHP doc comments), altough it seems to be very slow (I would not suggest it):

```
  function is_array_reference ($arr, $key) {
        $isRef = false;
        ob_start();
        var_dump($arr);
        if (strpos(preg_replace("/[ \n\r]*/i", "", preg_replace("/( ){4,}.*(\n\r)*/i", "", ob_get_contents())), "[" . $key . "]=>&") !== false)
            $isRef = true;
        ob_end_clean();
        return $isRef;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the solutions you will find on SO are broken (see explanation below). The function I propose works for all arrays and is much more efficient than `print_r`:

```php
function is_cyclic(&$array) {
    $isRecursive = false;
    set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) use (&$isRecursive) {
        $isRecursive = $errno === E_WARNING && mb_stripos($errstr, 'recursion');
    });
    try {
        count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE);    
    } finally {
        restore_error_handler();
    }
    return $isRecursive;
}
```

The `count` function takes a second parameter `$mode` that can be set to the constant `COUNT_RECURSIVE` to count recursively ([see docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)). If a recursive array gets passed to `count`, it will emit a warning that we can trap and check. I have written more about this solution [on my blog](https://hbgl.dev/detecting-cyclic-arrays-in-php-a-new-approach/). Tests and benchmarks are on [github](https://github.com/hbgl/demo-detecting-cyclic-arrays-in-php-a-new-approach).

#### Why are most solutions broken?

Any implementation that adds markers to arrays and then later checks for the presence of these markers does not work for all inputs. Specifically, they fail to detect recursion in some cases where the arrays have previously been assigned by value (e.g. returned by a function). This is due to the way PHP handles value assignments of arrays, as described in [chapter 4 of the PHP Language Specification](https://phplang.org/spec/04-basic-concepts.html#value-assignment-of-array-types-to-local-variables). I have written more extensively about this [on my blog](https://hbgl.dev/why-it-is-impossible-to-detect-cyclic-arrays-in-pure-php/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest and easiest way to check RECURSION is simple query

```
if(array(($variable['variable_name'])==('*RECURSION*')))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: to eliminate the php error related to the variable you can use the is_ function `if((is_array(($variable['variable_name']))==('*RECURSION*'))){return true;}else{return false;}`