# PHP, Is a copy of object created to be eliminated in some cases?

Tags: php, performance, oop

I have doubts as PHP objects behave after they have been deleted in some cases, doing some tests. Be the code:

```
class ItemRecord
{
    private $id;
    protected $name;

    public function __contruct($pID, $pName)
    {
        $this->id = $pID;
        $this->name = $pName;
    }
    public function setName($pName)
    {
        $this->name = $pName;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

I Create some objects of the ItemRecord Class and then, append them to the object list (an Array):

```
$objList = array();

$obj1 = new ItemRecord("1", "Object 1");
$objList[] = $obj1;
$obj2 = new ItemRecord("2", "Object 2");
$objList[] = $obj2;
```

If I change some property in the 'original' object, for example:

```
$obj1->setName("FOO");
```

And then I'll try to show the content of the 'linked' element in the list with the original object:

```
echo($objList[0]->getName()); //-> Of course, It displays "FOO"
```

So if I delete the object should not exist in the list anymore

```
unset($obj1); unset($obj2);
```

But it's not like that!

```
echo($objList[0]->getName());
```

It continues displaying "FOO"!, and **the object continues existing** as well...

**So my question is: In this case, when you delete an object, a copy operation occurs at delete time?**

There are other curious cases like this strange behavior, but for now I will

**UPDATED:** After the answers and things have been talked in comments. Maybe it would be great **if the unset() function could return the result of deleting**. For example: 'true', if the var content or object could be finally removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question :  NO.

When you unset a value you are just removing a reference to that variable you are not actually deleting that. It will be deleted when there is no reference to that variable exits.

From PHP Documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

> unset() destroys the specified variables

Comment: So, is the memory freed when make the unset($object)?

Comment: So the answer is: **The object (content) is not removed until all its references are removed?**

Comment: I understand. Sorry if the question was trivial, I have simplified my real case, on which I had doubts, in this question. Where there were objects that were assigned to attributes of other objects etc, and I had found a strange situation in some unset sentence. Thanks!

Comment: I think the PHP "[decon](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)" page may help. Also [GC](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) has a hint too. Zzz I commented on wrong post, sorry. (should be on op)

Comment: So it is important to know, in some cases, **if exist other variables referencing to the object we want to eliminate**. to be sure that will be completly removed etc.

I found this. Or there are other better ways to knowing it?
[detecting-whether-a-php-variable-is-a-reference-referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817562/detecting-whether-a-php-variable-is-a-reference-referenced)