# Know if an element of an array is a reference

Tags: php, reference

How can I tell if an element in an array is a reference?

Consider the following code:

```
$a = ['a1', 'a2'];
$b = ['b1', &$a];

var_dump($b);
```

The output of `var_dump($b)` is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "b1"
  [1]=>
  &array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "a2"
  }
}
```

As you can see, var_dump() knows that array $a is by reference inside array $b.

Is there a way to tell that an element of an array is actually a reference?

Comment: I don't know of any bulletproof way of checking that, but may I ask why you need it and what problem it would solve? Imho, if you need to know that at runtime, it's probably a sign of some bigger design flaw.

Comment: check this links : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817562/detecting-whether-a-php-variable-is-a-reference-referenced   and check this :  http://xdebug.org/ . found that may be usefull