# debug_zval_dump and refcount

Tags: php

Is there any way to get the *refcount* value reported by **debug_zval_dump** without all the additional information returned by that function; e.g. by an alternative function or some truncation of its output?  I am using the *refcount* as per the suggested solution to the problem [Detecting whether a PHP variable is a reference / referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817562/detecting-whether-a-php-variable-is-a-reference-referenced).  As such, all I require is the reference count.  The structure I am examining is huge so (a) getting the entire structure seems like overkill and (b) I believe I've seen cases where the size has caused problems and bypassing the output buffer (NB: No *chunk_size* had been set for the ob_start).

Comment: There's no way without a third party extension. What exactly do you want to do with the `refcount`?

Comment: @netcoder - I want to solve the problem in the question to which I linked.  I'm hitting issues with large data structures.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110973/compare-php-arrays-using-memory-references) may interest you.