# PHP Catching a SimpleXMLElement parse error

Tags: xml, simplexml, php

I have a script that parses some XML (adf) stuff. Sometimes we receive broken XML data (ie- syntax, no ending tag, etc.).

`SimpleXMLElement` throws an error and kills my script, how could assign something like `$xml_body = new SimpleXMLElement ($adf_xml);` and catch the parse exception?

---

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home//Work//script/email_leads.php:46
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /home//Work//script/email_leads.php(46): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<?xml version="...')
>   1 /home//Work//script/email_leads.php(97): generateFeed()
>   2 {main}

Comment: Uhm, are you sure that using SimpleXML here is what you want? If you expect non-wellformed data you shouldn't use draconian xml certainly, but use some DOM parser instead.

Comment: this is a chron'd script that gets input from an INBOX (imap)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: catch exception and continue execution, is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132759/php-catch-exception-and-continue-execution-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 12):

Ok, so apparently catching XML Parse errors is somewhat of a Holy Grail... I ended up just

```
try { $x = new SimpleXMLElement($y, LIBXML_NOERROR); } catch (Exception $e) { echo $e; }
```

#### EDIT: thanks to @PanPipes

Comment: try / catch doesn't seem to work with SimpleXMLElement. Or at least it didn't for loading a non-xml file for me.

Comment: I found this did not work for me too. I had to use:
$x = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlString, LIBXML_NOERROR); 
This seem to give me a catchable Exception. For reference see PHP manual for [LIBXML_NOERROR](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php)

Comment: @PanPipes works for App Engine Standard Environment

Answer (score 7):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Comment: libxml_use_internal_errors does clear up the error logs a bit, my script is still going to die when it throws the Parse error... Thanks for the help/tip tho :)

Comment: I once up vote for the top voted answer, however, I think it is better to supress the error by the function mentioned here. And you use libxml_get_errors or libxml_get_last_error to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

`xml_parse` returns a boolean value indicating whether the XML has been parsed successfully.  Therefore, this should work:

```
$fp = fopen($xml_file, "r");
$xml_data = fread($fp, 80000);

if(!(xml_parse($xml_parser, $xml_data, feof($fp)))){
    # do something
}
```