# Using try Catch get the warning message in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Catching a SimpleXMLElement parse error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137645/php-catching-a-simplexmlelement-parse-error)

I am using xml file for file upload. I have use `simplexml_load_file("files/sample.xml");`
If given xml file error means, it will show warning like this,

```
Warning (2): simplexml_load_file() [http://php.net/function.simplexml-load-file]: files/sample.xml:8: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch:
Warning (2): simplexml_load_file() [http://php.net/function.simplexml-load-file]:
```

I have get warning using try catch. I am using cakePHP

Comment: Isn't it obvious that this depends on the input file? Show it! Unless the question isn't about the warning.

Comment: Here i am using, try{
         $xml = simplexml_load_file("files/sample.xml");
      }
      catch (Exception $e){
       //$this->set('err_msg',"Invalid XML file");
       echo "Invalid";
       exit;
      }

Comment: That are warnings, not exceptions. You can not "catch" them with a `try {} catch {}` block.

Comment: If given xml is wrong show error message to user.

Comment: Then get them: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php

Answer (score 1):

Your script is loading the file. However, the file cannot be parsed as XML.

To stop warnings being automatically spit out onto the page (it'll do this regardless of whether or not you try/catch), you'll need to use:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Before dealing with any class that uses libxml.

[Description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) from PHP.net:

> libxml_use_internal_errors — allows you to disable standard libxml errors and enable user error handling.

Comment: By using this libxml_use_internal_errors(true); page display as empty.

Comment: how to pass error message as invalid xml file to user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try/catch a warning, you have to 'convert' the warning into a exception.

Set your global error handle like this:

```
set_error_handler( 'error_handler' );
```

and then convert the warning to a exception:

```
function error_handler( $errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars )
  {
    // error was suppressed with the @-operator
    if ( 0 === error_reporting() )
      return false;

    if ( $errno !== E_ERROR )
      throw new \ErrorException( sprintf('%s: %s', $errno, $errmsg ), 0, $errno, $filename, $linenum );

}
```

Comment: A better way would be to use libxml_use_internal_errors(true), which allows you to handle errors yourself.